# Medicine cabinet wall “punched out”

Tags: bathroom, cabinets

i have a medicine cabinet where the back wall of the medicine cabinet was “punched out” resulting in about a 1 inch gap between the back wall of the cabinet and the shelves and side of the cabinet at the bottom right of the cabinet. Logically i suspect i could get it back into place if i could push the back wall back into place, but naturally the bathroom wall is in the way. Do you have any advice on how to get the back wall back into place? Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: i would hotglue some handles (blocks, fabric strips, etc) to the backer so i could forcibly tug it forward. you can remove them with a hair dryer once it's been repositioned.

Comment: @dandavis The problem is that if this, as I suspect, cardboard with a printed face, the glue (despite best efforts) could ruin it. That would work fine with actual painted/stained wood - but if it were actual wood it probably never would have come apart.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that the back panel is the typical thin cardboard used on a lot of bookcases and cabinets. That is held in by small nails (brads) and can come loose relatively easily if the back panel is not directly against a solid wall.

The best solution is:

- Remove the door (hinges may easily come apart, if not unscrew them from either the door or the cabinet)
- Figure out how the cabinet is attached to the wall and undo it. This may be one or more screws or nails visible from inside the cabinet. Or it may require removing some part of the frame. Hard to guess. And there is a non-zero possibility that it is just jammed into place and careful prying around the frame will get it out.
- Add some metal brackets along the edges (I'd do all 4 edges, not just the one that is currently the problem) to hold the back to the sides.
- Alternatively, (thank you FreeMan) particularly if the back is cardboard rather than wood:

  - Cut a piece of 1/4" plywood to match the size of the cabinet.
  - Place the plywood behind the existing back and screw it into the side pieces.
- Replace the cabinet, secure it and attach the door.

Comment: I would give the back a good look over. If it looks damaged, just replace it with a piece of 1/4" plywood. A full size 4x8' sheet isn't _too_ expensive even these days, and if it's out of budget, usually smaller "project panels" can be had at the big box store. Or, try an actual lumber yard. They're likely to have something about the right size and are likely much cheaper.

Comment: @FreeMan That won't match the color of the cabinet. But it is a good idea - updating my answer. Thank you.

Comment: That "small piece (2'x2')" is what they call a "project panel" 'round here, and is what I was referring to. Also, if the color doesn't match, just a few aisles down, the big-box will also sell stain. ;)

Comment: Oops. I didn't catch the project panel reference in the original comment (I see it now...) and you are 100% correct. But stain or paint to match is a huge hassle for this. As long as the problems are only the edges, plywood behind the existing back is a great solution.